# Does an electomagnetic field "modulate" an electric field?

Tags: waves

Lets imagine an electromagnetic wave is vertically polarized. If you ignore the magnetic component, the electric field lines would point upwards from the ground or downwards in a cyclical way and of course vary in field strength.

Now lets say you attach a battery to two metal plates and you produce an electric field having an horizontal polarization/direction.

Does the presence of an electromagnetic wave "modulate" the horizontally orientated electric field, in terms of it's strength and direction?

Answer (score 2):

Electric (and magnetic fields, or if you prefer, the electromagnetic field) are vector fields that are solutions to Maxwell's equations. These solutions obey the principle of superposition - i.e. if one field is a solution to Maxwell's equations and so is another, then the vector sum of these fields is also a solution.

Thus the answer to your question is yes, in the example you quote, the EM wave provides a spatial and temporal perturbation to the static horizontal field.

Comment: So, if we put numbers to thios:

Comment: So, if we put numbers to this: If E1 is the electric field strength of the steady electric field we have set up with the battery, with the strength of 1 volt/m which is horizontal, and if E2 is the electric field strength associated with the electric field of the electromagnetic wave also  at a strength of 1 volt/m (peak), E1 will achieve a maximum value of 1.414 volt/m, and vary in the vertical plane in a sinusoidal manner.

Comment: Well, at any position it will vary sinusoidally with time also.